# Change a variable name in all places in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code in Python3 using the IDE Wing, but I want to change a variable name, e.g., `var_1`, to `var_2` in all places in my file. In MATLAB, when you change a variable name in one place, by `Shift`+`Enter` it is automatically done for all other occurrences of that variable in the file. Is there any similar way to do it in Python?

Comment: This is not at all a property of the language: it's a function of your editor (sometimes embedded in your development environment).  Look up "global change command" in the applicable documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can accomplish this using nearly any text editor you want by using the *Find and Replace* feature.

The normal keyboard shortcut (including python's IDLE) for this is `Ctrl+H`, though different editors have different shortcuts.

Answer (score 8):

In WingIDE you have the option via the Refactor Menu to do Rename Symbol.

This does an intelligent replace, and also takes care of distinguishing global variable from class attributes with the same name.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Python Idle(GUI) you can Ctrl + H and select Replace All.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code is Ctrl + Shift + L and begin typing. 
Sublime/Atom are alt + F3.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the PyCharm IDE use Mayus + F6 on the variable that you want change and write the new name variable.